# Export table stored as list to Excel

Tags: r, list, matrix, datatable

I have balanced my population through `WeightIt` and I used `bal.tab` from `cobalt` package to create a table with the summary characteristics of my balanced population.

```
library(cobalt)
library(WeightIt)

data("lalonde", package = "cobalt")

W.out <- weightit(treat ~ age + educ + race + married + nodegree + re74 + re75,
                  data = lalonde, estimand = "ATT", method = "ps")

balanced_population <- bal.tab(W.out)
balanced_population
```

However, the results from `bal.tab` are stored as list, how can I save it as table or matrix and subsequently as an Excel file?

I found in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71114103/export-list-of-tables-as-a-object-in-xlsx-file) this solution but I keep getting an error although I installed the package correctly - plus I don't know if it should work in this case:

```
expss::xl_write_file(table, filename="test.xlsx")
Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘openxlsx’
```

Can anyone please provide a solution? The simplest as possible. I just want to export the results so I don't have to copy all the numbers each time.

Comment: Have you installed openxlsx?

Comment: @zephryl Thank you, although it doesn't work in this case because there is an error: Error in as.data.frame.default(x, optional = FALSE, check.names = FALSE,  : 
  cannot coerce class ‘c("bal.tab.bin", "bal.tab")’ to a data.frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`balanced.population` is a named list:

```
names(balanced_population)
[1] "Balance"      "Observations" "call"
```

So you can access each list element using *e.g.*

```
balanced.population$Balance
```

If you examine the structure of the list using

```
str(balanced.population)
```

you'll see that `balanced.population$Balance` is a data frame with 10 rows and 3 columns.

There appears to be an issue with your installation of `openxlsx`. Personally I would not bother writing to an Excel file, when you can easily write to a CSV file which Excel can import.

```
write.csv(balanced_population$Balance, "balance_data.csv")
```

Comment: @neiflfws Thank you so much!! It works!! Openxlsx didn't work anyway in this case even after installation. (Error in as.data.frame.default(x, optional = FALSE, check.names = FALSE, : cannot coerce class ‘c("bal.tab.bin", "bal.tab")’ to a data.frame )